# Salesforce Communities Spring '17 Error

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder, spring17

I woke up the morning after the Spring '17 release and my Koa community template is permanently in mobile mode.  I removed all of my custom CSS and everything is still stuck in mobile.  Has anyone seen this?

I decided to try to create a new community in a new sandbox and I'm receiving the error `Login is required to access this salesforce.com URL. Please contact your administrator if you feel this is an error.`

I tried debugging the error, but no logs are produced.  I made sure my sys admin profile had all required permissions, and that all of the community page/controllers are accessible.  Still no luck.  Any advice?

Edit: If you're seeing the error `Login is required to access the salesforce.com URL` try renaming the community.  Either the issue magically resolved itself, or it was throwing an error because the community name (not url) already existed in the sandbox.

Edit 2: After doing some digging it seems that salesforce is trying to force my page through some sort of "login" template.  I inspected the page and found the container wrapped in the `salesforceIdentityLoginBody` class, replacing the actual login page with our index.  Our community is anonymous and doesn't require login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SF support confirmed this was a problem with their Spring 17 release.  If you're facing this problem contact support.  There is no way to fix this yourself without creating a whole new community.