# Error accessing community

Tags: community

While I try accessing community in our production org, it errors out with the message

> */{"message":"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 2028041626-38896 (181524616)"}/*ERROR*/

Is Salesforce communities down ? I don't see any update in trust.salesforce.com .

Org is in Spring 17 release and the error is after login,when user tries to switch to the community.

Comment: Can you post any screenshot?

Comment: @Rahul, the message I have posted is all I get when I try access community.

Comment: Are you on Spring'17? There is a similar question posted today : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160150/salesforce-communities-spring-17-error

Comment: When are you getting that exception, in login page or after login. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: javanoob, Rahul - I have updated original question with more information. Hope this helps.